# Notifying cocoa bindings system when code changes a property by instead of the interface

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder, cocoa-bindings

I'm writing a countdown timer and instead of calling `-[NSTextField setDoubleValue:secondsRemaining]` on each tick, I'd like to bind the `secondsRemaining` property to an interface element via an object controller.

The problem with this is that `secondsRemaining` is modified by code on each tick, not by the interface, so the change is doesn't seem to be broadcast.

I have two parts to the question:

1) Is this a sensible way to use bindings or should I stick with `-[NSTextField setDoubleValue:]` in my App controller?

2) If I do use bindings, how do inform the interface that the value has changed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either use a KVO-compliant setter or [send manual notifications](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Concepts/AutoVsManual.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001844-BAJEAIEE) when you mutate the value.

Comment: Preferably the former. It's much, *much* easier.